# "Empty pipe not allowed" in foreach loop

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

I was asked to fix up the output of a PowerShell script a colleague wrote today, and noticed some strange behavior when trying to pipe output from a `foreach` loop. When I run the loop without piping the iterable object `$gpos` into the `foreach` as so:

```
# This is the foreach loop in question
foreach ( $gpo in $gpos ) {
  [xml]$XML = Get-GPOReport -$gpo.DisplayName -ReportType Xml
  $admins = $XML.DocumentElement.Computer.ExtensionData.Extention.RestrictedGroups.Member

  # Not this one 
  $admins | foreach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      "GroupPolicy" = $gpo.DisplayName;
      "Permisisons" = $_.name.'#text';
    }
  }
} | Export-CSV -Path \path\to\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I get an error "An empty pipe element is not allowed".

However, if I pipe the `$gpos` object into the `foreach` loop like so:

```
$gpos | foreach {
  $gpo = $_
  # ...the rest of the code above
} | Export-CSV -Path \path\to\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I am able to use the last pipe without issue. Why won't the pipe work when the statement starts with a `foreach` loop as opposed to piping in the iterable object? I rarely use the first format myself, so I've not run into this issue with code I write. I can't think of a functional reason both formats shouldn't work because if the piped input is null there is an appropriate exception which is thrown in this case.

Comment: You can wrap iteration statements in subexpressions `$(foreach($thing in $things){...}) | ...` if you want to feed output from the loop into the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why won't the pipe work when the statement starts with a `foreach` loop as opposed to piping in the iterable object?

Because one syntax is the `foreach` statement, and the other is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` command.  It's like the difference between `Get-ChildItem` and `if {} else {}`.

The PowerShell authors stupidly decided that overloading the term was a good idea.  It's confused users of the language ever since.

Compare:

```
Get-Help about_Foreach -ShowWindow

Get-Help ForEach-Object -ShowWindow
```

The former even describes how PowerShell decides which is which:

> When Foreach appears in a command pipeline, Windows PowerShell uses the foreach alias, which calls the ForEach-Object command. When you use the foreach alias in a command pipeline, you do not include the ($ in $) syntax as you do with the Foreach statement. This is because the prior command in the pipeline provides this information.

Bottom line is that the `foreach` will not send output down the pipeline.  You can do this just fine:

```
$x = foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i }
```

But this will fail:

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i } | Where-Object { $_ -eq 2 }
```

As Mathias R. Jessen notes in the comments, you can wrap the `foreach` statement in a subexpression to cause it to work with the pipeline:

```
$(foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i }) | Where-Object { $_ -eq 2 }
```

The `ForEach-Object` command always uses (and requires) the pipeline.

Comment: Man as much as I love Powershell..... wtf devs. Just looked up the differences between the foreach statement and foreach-object, and really they should have overloaded with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

One is the language keyword `foreach` and the other is actually an alias to the cmdlet `ForEach-Object`.

A language keyword can't be a part of a pipeline which is why you get that exception.  It's also why they mean different things in different contexts, the engine won't parse `foreach` as a keyword if it's already part of a pipeline.