# how do i pass the selected string into a variable?

Tags: docker, powershell, cmd, github-actions

how do i store the output of a command into a variable for use in a github-actions .yaml?

```
docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | select -first 1
```

gives me:

```
fc6e040841a1
```

i've seen stuff online about select-object..but i honestly have no idea, just trying to push an image to a registry...

the following cmd doesn't work in powershell:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ("docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | select -first 1") do @set "%_img%=%a"
```

Comment: Try `$env:_img = docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | select -first 1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i probably dont know what im doing..but echo and Write-Host don't seem to give me anything back but %_img% or _img

Comment: Shameless plug, the complexity in assigning results to a variable *alone* is why I refuse to even maintain existing batch scripts anymore. I will use existing ones if they work but if it needs to be changed I'm porting it to PowerShell.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest great point, i will try to learn more, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the following cmd doesn't work in powershell:
>
> ```
> for /f "delims=" %a in ("docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | select -first 1") do @set "%_img%=%a"
> ```

That's because this is Command Prompt syntax. *Specifically*, everything outside of the `()` would only work under `cmd.exe`. The PowerShell equivalent for assigning a command result to a variable is:

```
$variableName = COMMAND
```

To apply it to your use case:

```
$imageId = docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | Select-Object -First 1
```

---

Note that `select` is an alias of `Select-Object` and either can be used interchangeably.

---

Edit: While not required for setting variables unlike in the Command Prompt, `for` syntax is still different in PowerShell when batch scripting. You can read up on PowerShell's [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.1), [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1), and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) constructs when you want to learn how they are used in PowerShell scripts, and watch for [this gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870546/584676) when using the `foreach` "statement" as part of a pipeline.

---

While not part of the original scope of the question, since OP *did* ask and I answered in the comments, I will put the `bash` equivalent here for the sake of completeness and how I transposed this from the PowerShell method I used above:

```sh
imageId=$(docker images --format="{{.ID}}" | head -n 1)
```

This is similar to the PowerShell syntax with a few changes: remove the `$` from the variable name on assignment, and `Select-Object` is replaced by `head`. You can't pad the `=` with whitespace, and you have to subshell the command with `$()`.

Comment: ok...i guess i thought because i was testing in powershell that that's how github does it...any chance you know how to translate this into bash?  im hoping for a hail mary

Comment: Really you should ask another question for doing this in `bash`, but it's not much different: `imageId=$(docker images --format="{{.ID}}" | head -n 1)`. Basically, remove the `$` from the variable name on assignment, and `Select-Object` is replaced by `head`. Oh, and no spaces allowed to pad the `=`, and you have to subshell the command with `$()`

Comment: whats the best way to learn all these os syntaxes?  im learning to use python and discovering that batch/bash/powershell are just as important

Comment: Honestly, practice and time. I would recommend focusing on mastery of one language first, then it becomes easy to search for the same logic constructs in other languages. Once you know one, you can learn them all, most languages share the same logical constructs, they are just expressed with different syntax and implementations under the hood.

Comment: Well except for languages like [`brainfuck`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)... but let's not open that can of worms